# QTCharts, how do I make the chart follow the x-axis as live data comes in?

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, charts, qtcharts

I'm attempting to make a chart that reads in data live. I started from the example Qt provides called "dynamic spline".

The issue I'm having is, the scroll() function appears to scroll pixels and there doesn't appear to be any function in Qt that I can find that scrolls along with the data. So unless I get the pixes scroll count exactly right, either my plot line grows until the end is no longer visible, or the chart scrolls on by leaving the plot line behind.

This to me seams like a rather obvious feature everyone would use with a dynamic chart, so I'm left asking the question: what feature in Qt charts am I missing that does this?

All my searching has been in vain, I haven't even been able to find a tutorial on how to use dynamic data collection in Qt charts.

```
#include "chart.h"
#include <QtCharts/QAbstractAxis>
#include <QtCharts/QSplineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QValueAxis>
#include <QtCore/QTime>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

Chart::Chart(QGraphicsItem *parent, Qt::WindowFlags wFlags):
    QChart(QChart::ChartTypeCartesian, parent, wFlags),
    m_series(0),
    m_axis(new QValueAxis),
    m_step(0),
    m_x(10),
    m_y(1)
{
    qsrand((uint) QTime::currentTime().msec());

    QObject::connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(drawChart()));
    m_timer.setInterval(1000);

    m_series = new QSplineSeries(this);
    QPen green(Qt::red);
    green.setWidth(3);
    m_series->setPen(green);
    m_series->append(m_x, m_y);

    addSeries(m_series);
    createDefaultAxes();
    setAxisX(m_axis, m_series);
//    m_axis->setTickCount(11);
    axisX()->setRange(0, 100);
    axisY()->setRange(-5, 10);

    m_timer.start();
    elapsedTime.start();
}

Chart::~Chart()
{

}

void Chart::drawLine(qreal &x, qreal &y)
{
    m_series->append(x, y);
}

qreal Chart::getTime()
{
    return elapsedTime.elapsed() / 100;
}

void Chart::drawChart()
{
    qreal x = plotArea().width() / m_axis->tickCount();
    qreal y = (m_axis->max() - m_axis->min()) / m_axis->tickCount();
    m_x = getTime();
    m_y = qrand() % 5 - 2.5;
    drawLine(m_x, m_y);
    scroll(x, 0);

    qDebug() << getTime();
}
```

The code is pretty simple, right now it's plotting but the line and the scroll are totally out of sink. And since I want to use time as my X-axis, and can't use the nice unscalable way the example was setup with.

Right now the it's just plotting a random number. I'm not going to bother feeding it actual data until I get this scrolling thing sorted.

Thanks in advance for the help. And if you know of some good tutorials on Qt charts, I would greatly appreciate it. Qt tutorials, good ones anyway, are extremely hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

After much effort and throwing things against the wall to see what stuck, I discovered that scroll is not what you should use. You want to tie the range to your x-value, and update it every time you add data. This does force the graph to scroll as it were, along with the data line.

New problem, Charts in Qt has a built in memory leak.

Comment: Care to share your findings?

Comment: Nothing more to add. I stopped using Qt Charts. Far to painful, cumbersome and slow, and add to that it leaks memory like a siv, I switched to pyqtgraph and accomplished what I set out to do in python. As per usual, if nothing else works, just do it in python.

Comment: Thanks for response. I've seen some reports of memory leaks through QCharts but those seem to be resolved. When does this issue appear for you?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scroll try changing max value of axisX.

When you do your DrawLine check if the next point is higher than max and set a new max if yes :

```
if (m_x > m_axisX->max())
{
        m_axisX->setMax(m_x);
}
```

Comment: The max does not necessarily get displayed. Without changing the range, the max will flow right off the screen without complaint.